# Difference between HashSet and TreeSet

Tags: java

I want to know below objects usage:

```
HashSet hs = new HashSet();

TreeSet ts = new TreeSet();
```

Which one is more efficient in real-time scenarios?

Comment: Have you read the respective javadocs?

Comment: Ordering. Unordered will always be more efficient

Comment: When you were posting this question a whole list of other questions asking this same thing popped up. There is also a list of them on the right of your screen. Please don't ask questions that have already been answered.

Comment: which one is more performer when we retrieve the elements?

Comment: @user2173142 Please try to read JavaDoc before asking a question about a specific class. It usually describes details about its implementation. You should have done this in your other question about `List` vs `LinkedList` as well.